# Excel pass a subset range to another function

Tags: excel, function, range

I want to pass a subset of a range if some condition is met in a lookup column to function LINEST, how would I achieve this.

For simplicity, use the SUM function to demonstrate this.

```
    A   B
1   aaa 100
2   aaa 200
3   bbb 300
4   bbb 400
```

i.e if I filter on 'aaa' and pass this to SUM it should return 300.
for 'bbb' and pass this to SUM it should return 700

I was thinking it would look something like
=SUM(INDEX(B1:B4, A1:A4="aaa"))

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data as you give it is in `A1:B4`, **array formula****:

`=LINEST(INDEX(B:B,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(A1:A4="aaa",{1,1}*ROW(A1:A4)))))))`

Change the criterion (`"aaa"` here) as required.

Note that the part `{1,1}` may require changing if you are not using an English-language version of Excel.

Further reading at this link if interested:

https://excelxor.com/2016/02/16/criteria-with-statistical-functions-growth-linest-logest-trend/

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: The part about LINEST maybe?

Comment: Nice. Will attempt to do likewise from now on.

Comment: The ¹,² and ³ don't have to be hardcoded; `<sup>1</sup>` will do as well but charmap is still one of my favourite utility apps.